# Selenium2: Select option from dropdown causes window to disappear

Tags: soap, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

When I'm using the Select function from Selenium WebDriver, the windows completely disappears, but does stay active (as I can see in the taskbar). So it appears to be minimized, without losing focus.

This is causing certain test to fail.

```
void select(String locator, String option){
    WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
    Select selectBox = new Select(dropdown);
    selectBox.selectByVisibleText(option);
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you seeing is happen in? All browsers, or just one? This sounds like a known issue with IE only.

Comment: Exactly, this happens in IE8.

Comment: How is your question related to 'soap' ?